# Is it possible to have nested Servlet 3 web fragments

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I'm experimenting with Servlet 3 web fragments. Is it possible to have a web fragment within another web fragment? In other words I would have a web fragment jar in the WEB-INF/lib folder of a web fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a web fragment project then you do not have WEB-INF folder. Your web-fragment.xml is always in META-INF so it is impossible to nest web fragments.
However you can set up custom ordering and dependencies among web fragments e.g.:

```
<absolute-ordering>
    <name>name-of-web-fragment</name>
    <others />
</absolute-ordering>
```